# How to display the tick in items checked in the checkbox after reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to save the checked items in the checkbox and display them. I can store them locally and display. However the tick is not stored. Every time i reload the page the checked item that is stored is displayed but the tick is missing. Any idea on how to also store the tick in checked items and display them in the checkbox?

jsfiddle code I am currently trying is : https://jsfiddle.net/bhgmw7ey/

the html code is 
'

```
<div ng-repeat="chip in colores" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{chip.codigo}}" id="{{chip.codigo}}" ng-model="chip.checked" ng-change="chipsColores()"  ng-click="$storage.a = fav">
    <label>{{chip.codigo}}</label>
  </div>

    <div ng-repeat="favorite in $storage.a">
                     localStorage: {{favorite.codigo}}
             </div>

</div>
```

'

the javascript code is

```
(function() { angular.module('myApp',['ngStorage'])  .controller('favCtrl',[ '$scope', '$filter', '$localStorage', function ( $scope, $filter, $localStorage) {
    $scope.colores = [
{'nombre':'blue', 'codigo':'1111'},
{'nombre':'green', 'codigo':'2222'},
{'nombre':'red', 'codigo':'3333'}  ];

$scope.chipsColores = function () {
    $scope.fav = $filter('filter')($scope.colores, {checked: true});} $scope.$storage =  $localStorage.$default({    });}])})();'
```

Answer (score 0):

your ngStorage is not properly used referring to the official wiki of this library https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.

Following the get started guide u should implement the localstorage by bind it to a scope variable so that it can watch and update the variables in localstorage for u.

For ur case it should look like

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="favCtrl">


    <div ng-repeat="chip in $storage.colores" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{chip.codigo}}" id="{{chip.codigo}}" ng-model="chip.checked" ng-change="chipsColores()" >
        <label>{{chip.codigo}}</label>
      </div>

        <div ng-repeat="favorite in $storage.colores">
                         localStorage: {{favorite.codigo}}
                 </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
```

And JS:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngStorage'])

  .controller('favCtrl',[ '$scope', '$filter', '$localStorage', function ( $scope, $filter, $localStorage) {

    $scope.chipsColores = function () {
        $scope.fav = $filter('filter')($scope.$storage.colores, {checked: true});
}
//move the 'colores' into storage
  $scope.$storage =  $localStorage.$default({
    colores : [
    {'nombre':'blue', 'codigo':'1111'},
    {'nombre':'green', 'codigo':'2222'},
    {'nombre':'red', 'codigo':'3333'}

  ]
});


}])
```